# Detect if UITableView is in beginUpdates/endUpdates state

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I'm writing a small unit test for a UITableView and want to check there was a endUpdates method call. In other words, I want to check the UITableView is in the normal state but not in the "updating" state.

Is there a way (method, property or something) I can use to check the TableView state?

I thought about subclassing but it seems to complex for such a simple task.

Answer (score -5):

There is an inbuilt boolean value to check if the tableView is in editing mode or not.

to check the status use

```
if([tableView isEditing] == YES)
{
//enter code if in editing mode
}
else
{
//enter code for non editing mode
}
```

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: beginUpdates doesn't change isEditing property value

Comment: add this [self.tableView setEditing:YES]; when u beginUpdates, this will change isEditing value and u can revert it back when endUpdates is called. hope it helps.

Comment: @AnshukGarg, this won't work. Because some animation can continue after `endUpdates` call.